# DHF mlDeploy : Plugin [id: 'net.saliman.properties', version: '1.4.6'] was not found

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, marklogic, gradle-plugin, marklogic-dhf

While I was trying to deploy marklogic DHF project 5.4.x in my local using gradle mlDeploy, I was getting UnknownPlugin exception for net.saliman.properties. I am using gradle version 6.4.
And I could see this plugin available in the repository. Any leads on solving this issue is welcome.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\sharu\Desktop\datahub\data-data-hub\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'net.saliman.properties', version: '1.4.6'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.saliman.properties:net.saliman.properties.gradle.plugin:1.4.6')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Comment: Can you share what's in your build.gradle file? I'm wondering if you're using a buildscript and you're missing the plugins repository. If so, it's easier to just use the "plugins" syntax - see https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.saliman.properties

Comment: build.gradle file is bit long. But I can paste the part of it where plugin and repository is mentioned:

Comment: buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url "http://repository.intranet.*****.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins-remote/" }
  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6"
    }
  }
}

Comment: plugins {
  id "java"
  id "eclipse"
  id "idea"

  id "net.vivin.gradle-semantic-build-versioning" version "4.0.0" apply false
  id "net.saliman.properties" version "1.4.6"
  id "com.marklogic.ml-data-hub" version "4.3.2"
  id "distribution"
  id "maven-publish"
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.9.6"
  id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.4"
}

Comment: repositories {
  maven { url "http://repository.intranet.*****.com/artifactory/gradle-plugins-remote/" }
}

Comment: It looks like your buildscript/repositories is the problem. The error is most likely that your intranet repo does not have the saliman properties plugin in it. Thus, Gradle says it cannot find that plugin.